# React.cloneElement with style injection based on getBoundingClientRect() issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get a layout in which the container component dictates the `style` of the child components, or more specifically the `width` property of the children's style prop.

**TL;DR:** How to set children's props based on parent's `getBoundingClientRect()` for all renders, including the initial one.

I am able to calculate the desired width after the component mounts, using `getBoundingClientRect()` on the container component and then running it through my calculations, but for the initial render, this results in being a non-existent value, because obviously, it is still not in the DOM.

Example below:

```
class Container extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.containerRef = React.createRef();
        this.containerWidth = null;
        this.columnWidth= null;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.containerWidth = this.containerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().width;
        this.columnWidth = this.containerBaseWidth / this.props.columns;
    }

    injectChildrenWidth = () => {
        return React.Children.toArray(this.props.children)
            .map(el => {
                return React.cloneElement(
                    el,
                    { componentWidth: this.columnWidth }
                );
            });
    };

    render() {
        const Columns = this.injectChildrenWidth();
        return (
            <div ref={this.containerRef} >
                {Columns}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

What would be the proper way to allow the parent component to "dictate" the width of property of the child components based on it's own `getBoundingClientRect()` width? Initial render never has values for the parent because it is not in the DOM, and I need to get the value in order to render children, so I need the values in the `render()` method.

I am pretty sure that the whole conception is wrong and I should be looking at some different lifecycle method or smthing, just do not know where/what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use state

```
class Container extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.containerRef = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      containerWidth: undefined,
      columnWidth: undefined
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    let containerWidth = this.containerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    let columnWidth = containerWidth / this.props.children.length;
    this.setState({ containerWidth, columnWidth });
  };

  injectChildrenWidth = () => {
    return React.Children.toArray(this.props.children).map(el => {
      return React.cloneElement(el, { componentWidth: this.state.columnWidth });
    });
  };

  render() {
    const Columns = this.injectChildrenWidth();
    return <div ref={this.containerRef}>{Columns}</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: This would cause a re-render, would it not? Is there no way around it?

Comment: Yes it do re-render thing. Other way is you can try `react-sizeme`, but I think it's still re-render in children component.